# Xamarin binding object c library problems

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, static-linking

I'm tring to bind that library

https://github.com/Appsido/AOTag?source=cc

static library it's furnished from developer. I'm generated my Binding project and API Definition that is

```
using System.Drawing;
using System;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace AOTTagBinding {

    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface EGOImageLoader {

        [Static, Export ("SharedImageLoader")]
        EGOImageLoader SharedImageLoader { get; }

        [Export ("IsLoadingImageURL")]
        bool IsLoadingImageURL (NSUrl aURL);

        [Export ("LoadImageForURL")]
        void LoadImageForURL (NSUrl aURL, EGOImageLoaderObserver observer);

        [Export ("ImageForURL")]
        UIImage ImageForURL (NSUrl aURL, EGOImageLoaderObserver observer);

        [Export ("RemoveObserver")]
        void RemoveObserver (EGOImageLoaderObserver observer);

        [Export ("RemoveObserver")]
        void RemoveObserver (EGOImageLoaderObserver observer, NSUrl aURL);

        [Export ("HasLoadedImageURL")]
        bool HasLoadedImageURL (NSUrl aURL);

        [Export ("CancelLoadForURL")]
        void CancelLoadForURL (NSUrl aURL);

        [Export ("ClearCacheForURL")]
        void ClearCacheForURL (NSUrl aURL);

        [Export ("ClearCacheForURL")]
        void ClearCacheForURL (NSUrl aURL, string style);

        [Export ("currentConnections", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        NSDictionary CurrentConnections { get; set; }
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    [Model]
    public partial interface EGOImageLoaderObserver {

        [Export ("ImageLoaderDidLoad")]
        void ImageLoaderDidLoad (NSNotification notification);

        [Export ("ImageLoaderDidFailToLoad")]
        void ImageLoaderDidFailToLoad (NSNotification notification);
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIImageView))]
    public partial interface EGOImageView : EGOImageLoaderObserver {

        [Export ("InitWithPlaceholderImage")]
        IntPtr Constructor (UIImage anImage);

        [Export ("InitWithPlaceholderImage")]
        IntPtr Constructor (UIImage anImage, EGOImageViewDelegate aDelegate);

        [Export ("CancelImageLoad")]
        void CancelImageLoad ();

        [Export ("imageURL", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        NSUrl ImageURL { get; set; }

        [Export ("placeholderImage", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIImage PlaceholderImage { get; set; }

        [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        EGOImageViewDelegate Delegate { get; set; }
    }

    [Model, BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface EGOImageViewDelegate {

        [Export ("ImageViewLoadedImage")]
        void ImageViewLoadedImage (EGOImageView imageView);

        [Export ("ImageViewFailedToLoadImage")]
        void ImageViewFailedToLoadImage (EGOImageView imageView, NSError error);
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    [Model]
    public partial interface AOTagDelegate {

        [Export ("TagDistantImageDidLoad")]
        void TagDistantImageDidLoad (AOTag tag);

        [Export ("TagDistantImageDidFailLoad")]
        void TagDistantImageDidFailLoad (AOTag tag, NSError error);

        [Export ("TagDidAddTag")]
        void TagDidAddTag (AOTag tag);

        [Export ("TagDidRemoveTag")]
        void TagDidRemoveTag (AOTag tag);

        [Export ("TagDidSelectTag")]
        void TagDidSelectTag (AOTag tag);
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
    public partial interface AOTagList {

        [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        AOTagDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        [Export ("tags", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        NSMutableArray Tags { get; set; }

        [Export ("AddTag")]
        void AddTag (string tTitle, string tImage);

        [Export ("AddTag")]
        void AddTag (string tTitle, string tImage, UIColor labelColor, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor closeColor);

        [Export ("AddTag")]
        void AddTag (string tTitle, NSUrl imageURL, string tPlaceholderImage);

        [Export ("AddTag")]
        void AddTag (string tTitle, string tPlaceholderImage, NSUrl imageURL, UIColor labelColor, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor closeColor);

        [Export ("AddTags")]
        void AddTags (NSObject [] tags);

        [Export ("RemoveTag")]
        void RemoveTag (AOTag tag);

        [Export ("RemoveAllTag")]
        void RemoveAllTag ();
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
    public partial interface AOTag : EGOImageViewDelegate {

        [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        AOTagDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        [Export ("tLabelColor", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIColor TLabelColor { get; set; }

        [Export ("tBackgroundColor", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIColor TBackgroundColor { get; set; }

        [Export ("tCloseButtonColor", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIColor TCloseButtonColor { get; set; }

        [Export ("tImage", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIImage TImage { get; set; }

        [Export ("tImageURL", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        EGOImageView TImageURL { get; set; }

        [Export ("tTitle", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        string TTitle { get; set; }

        [Export ("tURL", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        NSUrl TURL { get; set; }

        [Export ("GetTagSize")]
        SizeF GetTagSize { get; }
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
    public partial interface AOTagCloseButton {

        [Export ("cColor", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
        UIColor CColor { get; set; }

        [Export ("InitWithFrame")]
        IntPtr Constructor (RectangleF frame, UIColor color);
    }
}
```

and build fine. I have creted my AOTDelegate as:

```
using System;
using AOTTagBinding;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation; 

namespace MyPorject
{
    public class TagDelegate: AOTagDelegate
    {
        public TagDelegate(){

        }
        public override void TagDistantImageDidLoad (AOTag tag){

        }

        public override void TagDistantImageDidFailLoad (AOTag tag, NSError error){

        }

        public override void TagDidAddTag (AOTag tag){
        }

        public override void TagDidRemoveTag (AOTag tag){

        }
        public override void TagDidSelectTag (AOTag tag){

        }
    }
}
```

and finally i have used in my ViewController in that way

```
AOTagList tags = new AOTagList();
            tags.Frame = new RectangleF(0.0f,
                                        50.0f,
                                        320.0f,
                                        300.0f);

            TagDelegate deleg = new TagDelegate();
            tags.Delegate = deleg;
            tags.RemoveAllTag ();
            tags.Tags = new NSMutableArray ();
            this.View.AddSubview(tags);
```

but there is that exception when i call RemoveAllTag()

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[AOTagList RemoveAllTag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7e61d740
```

**UPDATE**
With response i have made an update to API that is like this

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
public partial interface AOTagList {

    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
    AOTagDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("tags", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    NSMutableArray Tags { get; set; }

    [Export("addTag:withImage:")]
    void AddTag (string tTitle, string tImage);

    [Export ("addTag")]
    void AddTag (string tTitle, string tImage, UIColor labelColor, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor closeColor);

    [Export ("addTag")]
    void AddTag (string tTitle, NSUrl imageURL, string tPlaceholderImage);

    [Export ("addTag")]
    void AddTag (string tTitle, string tPlaceholderImage, NSUrl imageURL, UIColor labelColor, UIColor backgroundColor, UIColor closeColor);

    [Export ("addTags")]
    void AddTags (NSObject [] tags);

    [Export ("removeTag")]
    void RemoveTag (AOTag tag);

    [Export ("removeAllTag")]
    void RemoveAllTag ();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The binding generator (Objective Sharpie) has a bug where it doesn't output the correct selectors.

This means that all the string constants in your [Export] attributes are wrong.

For the RemoveAllTag method, this is most likely what it should say:

```
[Export ("removeAllTag")]
void RemoveAllTag ();
```

note the lower-case 'r' in the selector name.

Comment: That's some serious bug then. Perhaps ObjSharpie should be pulled until this gets fixed instead of giving newcomers endless headache :)

Comment: RemoveAllTag works fine. I have an update on my interface definition but i have however same problem with AddTag...

Comment: @LuigiSaggese AddTag(string, string) would be `Export("addTag:tImage:")`. You need to include the full signature of the ObjC method. But Sharpie should do that, unless that's another bug.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold: the new version of Objective Sharpie should be out now.

Comment: @Krumelur doesn't work as suggested by you. I have tried also `[Export("addTag:withImage:tImage:")]` but error it's always the same.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge when it'll be avaible to download and where?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese Sorry, typo. I meant: `[Export("addTag:withImage:")]`

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: afaik it'll get published to our docs (http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/) at any moment, but in any case here's a direct link to the new version: http://bit.ly/objectivesharpie-commandline-0440

Comment: @Krumelur thanks! New problem when `AddTag("test", "test.png");` on `NSCFString sizeWithAttributes:`...really dejected! :-(

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge why not document all errors with possible solutions and link to download? Now it's just a useful tool but not complete for use. Hope Xamarin could do something better for developers. I'm sure. That could also approach ObjC developers

Comment: @LuigiSaggese: It's still an alpha product, so a bit rough on the edges.

Comment: @LuigiSaggese What do you mean with "new problem on NSCFString"?

Comment: @Krumelur as suggested by you i have modified (in question too) `[Export("addTag:withImage:")]`. But when i call `AddTag("test", "test.png");` error is `NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFString sizeWithAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x80a90f60`